Is there a way to implement autosave functionality for a blog on Django default admin page
I've been trying to implement an autosave functionality for a blog I'm building with Django. I'm also using the default admin page. But it's not working.
So I tried using ajax to get the content from the post page, and send post requests to the function views. But it doesn't seem to be working. Is there a better way?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

yes, ajax is the way. but we can't help you further without code

So sorry for the very late reply. But I'd appreciate if I get the code, or a starter code. I deleted everything out of frustration.
